# Is there a way to check and see if a key in my dictionary in python is capital, and if it is append something to it?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I am trying to create a program that has a dictionary and converts a string to its braille representation in 1's and 0's. My problem is that I do not know what to do when the user enters a capital letter. if they enter that letter, I want to append 000001 before its letter representation. like Bob would look like "000001110000101010110000"

this is what I have so far

```
myDict = {'a' : '100000','b': '110000','c': '100100','d': '100110','e': '100010','f': '110100','g': '110110','h':'110010','i': '010100','j':'010110','k': '101000','l': '111000','m':'101100','n': '101110','o': '101010','p': '111100','q': '111110','r': '111010','s':'011100', 't': '011110','u': '101001','v': '111001','w': '010111','x': '101101','y': '101111','z': '101011'}
def braille(string, brailleDict):
    return ''.join(brailleDict[char] for char in string)
print(braille('bob', myDict))
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isupper.htm

Answer (score 3):

### Update your dictionary

The best approach would be to update your `brailleDict` to account for capital letters. Your initial solution would then work.

Although, this allows you to use the `str.translate` method which is arguably an even better solution.

```
brailleDict = {'a' : '100000', 'b': '110000', ...}

# Add the capital letter Braille representations to your dict
brailleDict.update({char.upper(): '000001' + code for char, code in brailleDict.items()})

# Create a translation dict to be used by `str.translate`
brailleTranslation = str.maketrans(brailleDict)

print('bob'.translate(brailleTranslation)) # '110000101010110000'
print('Bob'.translate(brailleTranslation)) # '000001110000101010110000'
```

The downside is that `str.translate` will leave characters it does not recognize unchanged. You can either check your string is translatable with `str.isalpha` and raise a `ValueError` if it isn't or update your translation table so it removes unknown characters.

```
from collections import defaultdict

...

brailleTranslation = defaultdict(lambda: None, str.maketrans(brailleDict))

print('#bob'.translate(brailleTranslation)) # still prints '110000101010110000'
```

If you populate your `dict` with all Braille characters, you can check for `s.isprintable()` instead in the above function.

### Use `str.upper`

Alternatively, you can check if a string is composed of uppercase characters using `str.isupper`.

```
brailleDict = {'a' : '100000', 'b': '110000', ...}

def braille(string):
    return ''.join(('000001' if char.isupper() else '')
                   + brailleDict[char.lower()] for char in string)

print(braille('bob')) # '110000101010110000'
print(braille('Bob')) # '000001110000101010110000'
```

Comment: what is your for loop doing in the updated one line 2

Comment: It loops over each letter in the brailleDict, capitalize it and adds it back to the dict by prepending '000001' to its value. This basically adds the capital letters to your dict.

Comment: Using `translate()` is good for this although it handles unknown characters by leaving them unchanged, which might not be desired.

Comment: It is true that translate offers that feature, but I'd personally add a check that raises an error if a character cannot be handled, since it makes no sense to have letters in a braille string.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: sorry, I meant that leaving them unchanged is a potential negative.

Comment: @mhawke I agree, I will add a fix to that

Answer (score 0):

```
myDict = {'a' : '100000','b': '110000','c': '100100','d': '100110','e': '100010','f': '110100','g': '110110','h':'110010','i': '010100','j':'010110','k': '101000','l': '111000','m':'101100','n': '101110','o': '101010','p': '111100','q': '111110','r': '111010','s':'011100', 't': '011110','u': '101001','v': '111001','w': '010111','x': '101101','y': '101111','z': '101011'}
def braille(string, brailleDict):
    return ''.join("000001{0}".format(brailleDict[char.lower()]) if char.isupper() else brailleDict[char] for char in string)

print(braille('bob', myDict))
print(braille('Bob', myDict))
```

**Output:**

```
110000101010110000
000001110000101010110000
```

- Use `str.isupper` to check if letter is capital

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add keys to your dictionary for each of the capital letters. The values would be prepended with the "shift" sequence. There would be no other changes to your `braille` function, and you would be able to add other symbols such as punctuation, digits, etc. simply by updating the dictionary.

```
braille_dict = {'a' : '100000','b': '110000','c': '100100','d': '100110','e': '100010','f': '110100','g': '110110','h':'110010','i': '010100','j':'010110','k': '101000','l': '111000','m':'101100','n': '101110','o': '101010','p': '111100','q': '111110','r': '111010','s':'011100', 't': '011110','u': '101001','v': '111001','w': '010111','x': '101101','y': '101111','z': '101011'}

# add upper case versions of letters   
shift = '000001'
braille_dict.update({k.upper(): '{}{}'.format(shift, braille_dict[k]) for k in braille_dict})

def braille(string, braille_dict):
    return ''.join(braille_dict[char] for char in string)

for s in 'bob', 'Bob', 'BOB', 'Sausage':
    print('{}: {}'.format(s, braille(s, braille_dict)))
```

**Output**

```
bob: 110000101010110000
Bob: 000001110000101010110000
BOB: 000001110000000001101010000001110000
Sausage: 000001011100100000101001011100100000110110100010
```